# Javascript geolocation not working on updated android chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I was using javascript geolocation.currentposition method to get the users location in my website it was working perfectly in my previous android chrome browser but. It's been a day that I have update my mobile chrome browser in latest one . And suddenly geolocation stop working . Can anyone please help me with this .

Thanks in advance 
With Regards 
Dushant j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in latest android chrome v81.0.4044.111

[Refer this thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/41258140?hl=en&authuser=2&msgid=41258140) for more information